# Ignore empty results of a loop with a SQL query with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a table of this kind :

```
avis,client,image_client,client_do
123,carrefour,,23
45,leclerc,,12
56,auchan,,69
89,casino,,96
```

As you can see, the column `image_client` is empty. I have added the column in this csv file.

My SQL datatable this kind of data

```
client_do        |  image_client
12                  12.png
90                  90.png
96                  96.png
```

I would like to add all the SQL data `image_client` in the csv column `image_client` where the rows have the same client_do.

At the moment, I have this code :

```
$Csv = Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\4_1_traitement.csv"
$i=0

function GenericSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
    while ($Reader.Read()) {
        $Reader.GetValue(0)
    }

    $Connection.Close()

}

ForEach ($Row in $Csv) {

    $query= $query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = {0}) BEGIN SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = {0} END" -f $Row.client_do
    $imagefile=GenericSqlQuery($sqlserver,$DB,$query)
    $i += 1
}
```

The problem is to ignore the empty results of the query and I have the error that says *the CommandText was not initialized* for the line `$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()` and *It is impossible to call a Null expression* for the line `while ($Reader.Read())`.

EDIT : Code corrected by BaconBits

Comment: Just pointing out: You seem to have an extra curly bracket in your code sample after `GetValue($1) }`

Comment: Thanks. I have forgotten to delete it even though I did in my main PS file ^^

Comment: Try to break down the problem more - post the smallest amount of code needed to replicate the problem. It seems like you're asking a few independent questions here which will likely disway people from posting an answer.

Comment: Agreed with @JacobColvin , as the final `END` in your SQL query will cause an error on SQL Server as well..

Comment: I will attempt to clarify the question since for me there is only one problem which is how to make it work...

Comment: "How do I make it work" this is not a singular question given what you posted. The title gives a different problem than a few things you put in your post. You could submit a question with a thousand problems and still ask your question and keep the same logic - try to break things down so there is a singular question and a singular answer, regarding a singular issue.

Comment: Ah okay. I see what you mean... I'll change the title then. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

I see several issues.

First, your SQL query has an `END` but no `BEGIN`.  If you want the `IF EXISTS` then should be either:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $Row.client_do) BEGIN SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $Row.client_do END
```

Or you can omit the `BEGIN...END` block entirely if you're only executing one statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $Row.client_do) SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $Row.client_do
```

However, strictly speaking, you don't need the `IF EXISTS` at all.  You're just making the query engine do more work and the only difference is that you'll get no result set at all instead of an empty result set which isn't much different as far as the SqlDataReader is concerned.  You should probably just be calling:

```
SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $Row.client_do
```

And then handling it in your script if you've got an empty result set.  I'm not sure it would require any coding changes, however.

Next, you can't call properties of embedded variables like you are.  If `$Row.client_do` is 12, then `"$Row.client_do"` will return something like `[DataRow].client_do`.  The PowerShell parser doesn't recognize an embedded period as the dot operator.  You need to use a subexpression like `"$($Row.client_do)"`.  So your query should be:

```
$query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $($Row.client_do)) BEGIN SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = $($Row.client_do) END"
```

Or:

```
$query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = {0}) BEGIN SELECT [image_client] FROM [dbo].[clients] WHERE [client_do] = {0} END" -f $Row.client_do
```

Third, in your function, this line does not make sense:

```
$Reader.GetValue($1)
```

`$1` is a variable with no value.  You're effectively calling `$Reader.GetValue($null)`, meaning the system is going essentially call `$Reader.GetValue(([int]$null))`.  It only works because `[int]$null` is `0`, but that appears entirely accidental.  It should just be:

```
$Reader.GetValue(0)
```

Finally, your entire methodology here uses string concatenation to build your query strings.  That means you're vulnerable to SQL injection.  If this is a one-time script that's fine, but if you're going to use this script repeatedly then I highly recommend you use parameterized queries.

---

Edit: Actually, I noticed something else.  Your loop doesn't make sense, and you're calling the function incorrectly.

```
ForEach ($Row in $Csv) {
    $query = ...
    $imagefile = GenericSqlQuery($sqlserver,$DB,$query)
    $i += 1
}
```

You're overwriting `$imagefile` on each iteration. and then not doing anything with it.

Also `GenericSqlQuery($sqlserver,$DB,$query)` doesn't work like you think it does.  As written, this is calling  `GenericSqlQuery -Server ($sqlserver,$DB,$query) -Database $null 
 -SQLQuery $null`.  This is one of the biggest PowerShell gotchas.  It has to be `GenericSqlQuery $sqlserver $DB $query` or `GenericSqlQuery -Server $sqlserver -Database $DB -SQLQuery $query`.

Your loop and end of script look something like:

```
ForEach ($Row in $Csv) {
    $query = ...
    $imagefile = GenericSqlQuery -Server $sqlserver -Database $DB -SQLQuery $query
    $row.image_client = $imagefile -join ','
    $i += 1
}
$Csv | Export-Csv -Path "exportfilename.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for all the clarifications. It helped cleared up my code. But yes, I do need to code in case of empty result sets since I have the error  that says _the CommandText was not initialized_ for the line `$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()`  and _It is impossible to call a Null expression_  for the line `while ($Reader.Read())`. I'll update the question right away.